# Priority queue which can be stored on disk?

Tags: caching, data-structures, priority-queue, disk

I need to implement a application which has a priority queue which has more than 100M records. My problem is I am not able to keep all this data in memory, so I need to store it on disk. Is there any cache solution where I can store all this information to disk?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? I'd be interested to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can solve this by using a B-tree with a few minor modifications.

B-trees are specifically designed to store sorted elements on-disk in a way that minimizes the number of disk reads necessary to locate any element. Because they store their elements in sorted order, you can use them as priority queues by performing insertions as normal and finding the minimum element by taking the leftmost element in the tree (i.e. the first element of the leftmost leaf node).

In a B-tree of order d, you can find the minimum element using O(log<sub>d</sub> n) disk reads and writes, where n is the total number of elements. Insertions and deletions will also only require O(log<sub>d</sub> n) disk reads and writes.

However, you can significantly speed this up by storing a pointer to the leftmost leaf node in the B-tree. This node will store the minimum key plus other keys close to the minimum. If you have this pointer, you can look up the minimum value in a single disk read by taking the first element in the node. This also speeds up the extract-min operation: you can delete the key directly from that node without having to search for it. There may be some B-tree rebalancing operations necessary to make this work, though you can show that these operations happen so infrequently that the *amortized* work to do a deletion is only O(1).

In other words, using a B-tree with a pointer to the leftmost leaf has the following time complexities in terms of disk reads and writes:

- find-min: **O(1)**
- insert: **O(log<sub>d</sub> n)**
- extract-min: **O(1)** amortized

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice answer. It occurs to me that you could also implement a skip list on disk, and the operations would have the same bounds. Although extract-min *might* be O(1) (not amortized). But given that the behavior of B-trees is well known, I'd be inclined to use your approach.

Comment: @JimMischel The main issue with skiplists is the number of disk writes required to get all the pointer changes made. A skiplist typically requires O(log n) disk reads/writes for an operation, which can be significantly greater than a B-tree.

Comment: O(log n) reads, certainly. But the average number of pointers per node is 2, so it shouldn't take more than 2 writes per insert/delete. That said, I see your point. I wonder if there's some way to reduce the number of reads. Something to ponder.

Comment: You can use an unrolled linked list, and add more pointers to it to skip more efficiently. Of course, when you do that you will find that the data structure you end up with is just a B+ tree with parent pointers.

Answer (score 0):

One standard improvement you can make to the B-tree approach mentioned by templatetypedef that is fairly close to optimal is to use a B-epsilon tree where updates to anything ahead of the lead pivot are strict.

For epsilon = 1/2, this means that each B tree node holds only sqrt(B) pivots but also holds a buffer of up to B - sqrt(B) elements-to-be-inserted that are split into chunks that are roughly of size sqrt(B). Whenever a chunk overflows, it is bulk-inserted to the corresponding child node. This has the downside of making random access point searches use twice as many disk reads since the depth of the tree is doubled, but it makes insert operations faster because they take O(log B / sqrt B) disk accesses amortized, and O(log B) disk accesses worst case.

Since for a priority queue you do not care as much about random access and you had a pointer to the lead node, you probably want a B-epsilon tree to speed up inserts to non-leading nodes. And of course, if you add the standard B+ tree optimization you also get fast iteration of the inserted values in sorted order.

(practical implementations may further add heuristic improvements like remembering the last child from each node that it flushed inserts to so that you insert directly to that child in cases where it is already in cache, to also speed up the common case where you are bulk inserting a range of values to the same leaf node. Another trick that sometimes comes in handy if latency spikes from amortized writes are not a problem is to have two standard B-trees, with one being of size sqrt(N) to cache inserts and the other of size N to do reads, since RAM size is typically smaller than the sqrt of the size of disk, in this case the smaller B-tree can be replaced by an adaptative radix trie or something similar.)